# How to find out if two numbers are relatively prime?

Tags: java, primes

I'm trying to write a method that will calculate if two numbers are relatively prime for an assignment. I'm primarily looking for answers on where to start. I know there is a method `gcd()` that will do a lot of it for me, but the assignment is pretty much making me do it without gcd or arrays.

I kind of have it started, because I know that I will have to use the `%` operator in a for loop.

```
public static boolean relativeNumber(int input4, int input5){
    for(int i = 1; i <= input4; i++)
```

Obviously this method is only going to return `true` or `false` because the `main` function is only going to print a specific line depending on if the two numbers are relatively prime or not.

I'm thinking I will probably have to write two `for` loops, both for `input4`, and `input5`, and possibly some kind of `if` statement with a logical `&&` operand, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well in case they are relatively prime, the greatest common divider is one, because - if otherwise - both numbers could be devided by that number. So we only need an algorithm to calculate the greatest common divider, for instance [*Euclid's method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm):

```
private static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    int t;
    if(b < a) {
        t = b;
        b = a;
        a = t;
    }
    while(b != 0){
        t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t%b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

And then:

```
private static boolean relativelyPrime(int a, int b) {
    return gcd(a,b) == 1;
}
```

*Euclid's algorithm* works in *O(log n)* which thus is way faster than enumerating over all potential divisors which can be optimized to *O(sqrt n)*.

Comment: Though this is very helpful, I am not able to use the gcd method on this assignment, although my professor gave me props for reading ahead and learning about that,

Comment: @Tony: well you can simply implement (add the first codefragment) yourself. `gcd` is - as far as I know - not implemented in the Java standard library.

Comment: You need an additional check in the beginning to confirm if a < b. Otherwise swap them and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** code for @williem-van-onsem answer;

```
func gcd(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    var b = b
    var a = a
    var t: Int!

    while(b != 0){
        t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t%b;
    }
    return a
}

func relativelyPrime(a : Int, b: Int) -> Bool{
    return gcd(a: a, b: b) == 1
}
```

Usage;

```
print(relativelyPrime(a: 2, b: 4)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package stack;

import java.util.Scanner; //To read data from console

/**
*
* @author base
*/
public class Stack {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // with Scanner we can read data
        int a = in.nextInt(); //first variable
        int b = in.nextInt(); //second variable
        int max; // to store maximum value from a or b
        //Let's find maximum value
        if (a >= b) {
            max = a;
        } else {
            max = b;
        }
        int count = 0; // We count divisible number
        for (int i=2; i<=max; i++) { // we start from 2, because we can't divide on 0, and every number divisible on 1
            if (a % i == 0 && b % i==0) {
                count++; //count them
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) { // if there is no divisible numbers
            System.out.println("Prime"); // that's our solutions
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Prime"); //otherwise
        }
    }
}
```

I think that, this is the simple solution. Ask questions in comments.

Comment: Please explain your answer, especially since the OP is doing it for an assignment. If he copy/pastes your code, he learns nothing.

Comment: Though this is true, I actually learned a lot. I didn't think about the fact that initiating a max would reduce the amount of work the program would have to do.

Also, he did use a logical && operator in a way I wouldn't have thought of. I also didn't think of using the count and making a condition of the count equaling 0 would obviously determine it as prime. This was more of a logic question. I can understand the coding just fine. I do thank you Beezy for your submission and kittycat3141 for addressing concern for my learning experience.

Comment: @kittycat3141, hmm, Did he ask me to teach him? This is SO, where you ask your trouble questions, and get the answers for them.

Comment: @Tony: actually, you can already stop at *sqrt(min(a,b))* which will increase the performance of this algorithm extremely (10 seconds if the original run took 100 seconds). Furthermore from the moment you find such element, you can `break`. And finally one better uses `Math.max` because this allows non-branching code.

Comment: @Beezy The comments you added are fine. IMHO a `here iz teh codez` answer is as bad as a `send me teh codez` question (which this question is not).

Comment: @kittycat3141, I think that there are a lot of ways to learn, and `copy/pastes your code` one of them.

Comment: @Tony, you can choose the better answer for you, which helped to solve your problems.

Comment: @Beezy: why is this class called `Stack`?

Comment: @CommuSoft, I prepared the class in Netbeans for solving problems from StackOverflow. Just For Fun.

Comment: Why output as "Prime" or "Not prime" when the question asked was to find if two numbers are Co-prime or not?