# How to use fraction in java

Tags: java, math, methods, fractions

Im currently making a program with a bunch of methods. In this method it's about fractions. The user is supposed to input an integer numerator and denominator, for example 9/5 (not with decimals like 3.2/1.4).

After the method has done it's work, it should return the result to the main method, in this case 1_4/5. The problem I'm having is that the answer has to be returned as a String. Can't get it to work.. If the returned integer or fraction is 0, it should also be handled in a "nicer way".

Haven't figured it out by a long shot, but here is the little code I've come up with so far. Maybe it's easier to understand the problem.
Thanks in advance!

```
public static String fraction(int numerator, int denominator){
        fractionQuota = numerator / denominator;
        fractionRest = numerator % denominator;
        return fractionQuota;
```

Comment: Make some examples for input and what you would expect to returned.

Comment: Think about the options you have to get the components of the answer. For example, integer division will give you the 1 in your example. How can you go about getting the remainder?

Comment: You know that you will need to be able to prime factor your numbers to simplify your fractions right? Also, what you could do is take the numerator and see how many times the denominator fits within it. Then make the mixed fraction an simplify it.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by " If the returned integer or fraction is 0, it should also be handled in a "nicer way"." that would only occur if the denominator is 0. You could just check for these cases

Comment: @Fungucide, the expected result looks like "1_4/5". Why would one need to simplify the fraction when you can simply get it directly with `%` like in the example? `System.out.println((9/5) + "_" + (9 % 5) + "/" + 5);` seems simple enough.

Comment: True well then I don't see the problem William Nyqvister is having. This seems pretty straight forward

Comment: My guess is it comes down to making it into a string and possibly how to make it "nicer" when it will have a leading `0`. But yes, pretty straight forward. @Fungucide

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: I've made the assumption that both the numerator and denominator are positive and that the denominator is *strictly* positive. The code "works", but is formatted as `-1_-4/5` which is not very nice.

First I think you want to *normalize* your fraction: reduce it such that `21/15` is brought back to `7/5` first. You can do this by first calculating the *greatest common divider*. I "borrowed" my [own method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28575558/67579):

```
private static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    int t;
    while(b != 0){
        t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t%b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Now that we have that, we can normalize the fraction:

```
public static String fraction(int numerator, int denominator){
    int div = gcd(Math.abs(numerator),denominator);
    numerator /= div;
    denominator /= div;
    //TODO
    //...
}
```

Next we need to find the integral part, this can be done with:

```
    int intPart = (numerator/denominator);
```

Next we can calculate the remainder part with:

```
    int remPart = numerator-intPart*denominator;
```

Finally we use `String.format` to put it all together in a `String`:

```
    return String.format("%d_%d/%d",intPart,remPart,denominator);
```

So the method reads:

```
public static String fraction(int numerator, int denominator){
    int div = gcd(Math.abs(numerator),denominator);
    numerator /= div;
    denominator /= div;
    int intPart = (numerator/denominator);
    int remPart = numerator-intPart*denominator;
    return String.format("%d_%d/%d",intPart,remPart,denominator);
}
```

**Demo**: you can use [this jDoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/wU).